# iPhone authentication process

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

I have trouble finding info on this topic. Please help me out here.

I need to pass arguments via POST or GET method to my web server and get a reply.

Basically, if using GET method, I want to do something like **server.com/?user=john&password=smith** and receive the dynamically generated HTML code that is done with my **php** script. All this without using the web browser on my app.

How is it usually done?

Comment: This is a VERY BAD IDEA - passing your username and password like that!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into `NSMutableURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`.

For example, you could use them like this do to a GET request to your server:

```
- (void)loginUser:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password {

    // GET
    NSString *serverURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourserver.com/login.php?user=%@&pass=%@", username, password];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serverURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if (connection) {
        connectionData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
}
```

This will send an asynchronous GET request to your server with the query string containing username and password.

If you want to send username and password using a POST request, the method would look something like this:

```
- (void)loginUser:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password {

        // POST
        NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&pass=%@",username,password];
        NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourserver.com/login.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [req setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
        [req setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

        if (connection) {
            connectionData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }
    }
```

In order to get the response from the server, you will need to implement the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods, for example:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate methods
#pragma mark -

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    // Called if you have an .htaccess auth. on server
    NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"your_username" password:@"your_password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    [connectionData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [connectionData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [connectionData release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {  


    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[connectionData bytes]
                                                  length:[connectionData length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // This will be your server's HTML response
    NSLog(@"response: %@",content);

    [content release];
    [connectionData release];
}
```

References:

[NSMutableURLRequest Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "highly recommended for such data"?! No, it really is not.

Comment: As opposed to passing the credentials in the query string, it is. Edited the answer to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done using a **NSURLConnection**. You can also use NSString's method stringWithContentsOfURL.